# How to retrieve images from database and place on JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I have a JSP page and it should get all the images from database and should to display on one table. My resultset object 'rs' is pointing to images. My code is like this:

```
String query = "select image from stock";
rst = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rst.next())
<%
<td><img height="89" src=<%rst.getString(1)%></td>
%>
  }
```

I know, getString will not work for BLOB type. I was even used getBinaryStream(), but not succeed. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is complete example ,](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/retreiveimage.shtml)

Note: Consider this example as reference only to understand the way,

Answer (score 4):

**User the following piece of code to convert Blob to byte[]:**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
int n = 0;
while ((n=in.read(buf))>=0)
{
   baos.write(buf, 0, n);
}
in.close();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

**Use Servlet to write your image:**

```
if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 0) {
 response.setContentType("image/jpg");
 response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
 response.getOutputStream().flush();
 response.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

**Use retrive your image using servlet request url in jsp:**

```
<img src="imageDisplayProcess.do?pKey=imageId" width="117" height="160"
 onError="loadImage()" onAbort="loadImage()" />

imageDisplayProcess.do?pKey=imageId //should be your image servlet URL
```

Comment: Conversion blob to `byte[]` is unnecessary. Just write `getBinaryStream()` to `getOutputStream()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a servlet and map it, to, say, `/image/*`
2. Use `src="image/<%= imageId %>`, where `imageId` is the unique id of each image in the db
3. in the servlet `getBinaryStream()` and transfer it (for example using `IOUtils.copy(..)`) to `response.getOutputStream()`
4. Set the `Content-Type` to `image/jpeg` or `image/png` (or whatever the type is)

Comment: InputStream sImage;
byte[] bytearray = new byte[1048576];
  int size=0;
  sImage = rst.getBinaryStream(2);
  response.reset();
  response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
  while((size=sImage.read(bytearray))!= -1 ){
  response.getOutputStream().write(bytearray,0,size);

Comment: like this i written, but i am getting "getOutputStream() has already been called for this response" exception.

Comment: @Hermanth - show the whole servlet code by editing the original question. It's not readable here.

Answer (score 0):

Just put response type as "image/jpg" and retrieve column using ResultSet

demo code written bellow---

```
     if(rs.next()){
       int len = imgLen.length();
       byte [] rb = new byte[len];
       InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
       int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
       response.setContentType("image/jpg");
       response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);
       response.getOutputStream().flush();
       }
```