# Retrieve image from oracle database and show image in jsp

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc, blob

I want to retrieve image from table named Image and column named image with type blob, but while running the code its giving the blob code like this-

> "oracle.sql.BLOB@193242d"

Please see my code for fetching and show the image on jsp page/browser:-

```
ResultSet resultset = 
     statement.executeQuery("select * from image where id = '" + id + "'") ;
```

Browser page:-

```
    <TABLE border="1">
        <TR>
           <TH>ID</TH>
           <TH>picture</TH>
       </TR>
       <TR>
           <TD> <%= resultset.getString(1) %> </TD>
           <TD> <%= resultset.getBlob(2) %> </TD>
       </TR>
   </TABLE>
   <BR>
```

Comment: Try using `resultSet.getBinaryStream().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

`oracle.sql.BLOB@193242d` is the response of `toString()` method, not the image.

**Second:**

```
ResultSet resultset = 
     statement.executeQuery("select * from image where id = '" + id + "'") ;
```

For sake of SQL Injection, please!

**Finally**
You cannot response `image` with `text` data in heart! Image must be retrieved via a separated cgi/servlet where the content type is set to `image`, so for your case.

```
<TD> <%= resultset.getString(1) %> </TD>
<TD> <img src="/get_img?id="<%=id%>/> </TD>
```

And later you need a servlet/cgi to respond the image as `get_img`

```
@WebServlet(name = "img", urlPatterns = {"/get_img"})
public class get_img extends HttpServlet{
doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
...
 resp.setContentType("image/jpg");//or image/whatever
  try(ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery()){//where ps is a PreparedStatement
   //set the content length, and respond image data
   //example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4332975/5266804
  }
...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a servlet to serve the images from DB, see [How to retrieve images from database and place on JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332907/how-to-retrieve-images-from-database-and-place-on-jsp)

Or you can embed the image data directly into the `src` attribute of an image tag: [I want to retrieve image from mysql database using servlet and show that image along with that user details in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110939/i-want-to-retrieve-image-from-mysql-database-using-servlet-and-show-that-image-a) - although this is recommendable only for small images (icons etc.).